# Why is 'print (52-80)*42' different than 'print 42*(52-80)' in Perl?

Tags: perl, operators, printing, math

Perl:: What is:

```
1. (52-80)*42
2. 42*(52-80)
```

Ans:

```
1. -28
2. -1176
```

**Why?**

Have fun explaining/justifying this please!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
print 42*(52-80) , "\n";
print ((52-80)*42) , "\n";
print (52-80)*42 , "\n";
print "\n";
my $i=(52-80)*42;
print $i, "\n";
```

Output:

```
> -1176
> -1176-28
> -1176
```

Comment: Given that there aren't enough newline characters in your output, I don't think this is the code you actually ran, is it?

Comment: @Ben Try it. It is indeed producing exactly that output. Hint: It's not a math or precedence problem, it's a parsing problem with the parentheses...

Comment: @John: I think Ben got that. Perl will even warn you, iirc. But where does your output get the `>` characters from? `print` does not usually insert them.

Comment: oh of course, sub-style calls vs function-style calls

Comment: I added the >'s to emphasise that it was output

Comment: The title and question are, of course, wrong.  The result of `-28` depends on a larger code snippet.

Comment: Nice catch, Anthony! I have to confess that though I don't like Perl I have to use it now and then, not too unfrequently, and I was completely lost until seeing Alex's answer :)

Comment: You are missing the critical `use warnings;`

Comment: We talk about this issue specifically in _Learning Perl_. People might think it's a waste of time to read the book, but I wonder how much time people waste not reading it.

Comment: Please replace the backquotes in the title - they are confusing.

Answer (score 25):

If you add [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) you'll get:

```
print (...) interpreted as function at ./test.pl line 5.
Useless use of a constant in void context at ./test.pl line 5
```

Answer (score 17):

The warning that Alex Howansky aludes to means that

```
print (52-80)*42 , "\n"
```

is parsed as

```
(print(52-80)) * 42, "\n"
```

which is to say, a list containing (1) 42 times the result of the function `print(-28)`, and (2) a string containing the newline. The side-effect of (1) is to print the value `-28` (without a newline) to standard output.

If you need to print an expression that begins with parentheses, a workaround is to prepend it with `+`:

```
print +(52-80)*42, "\n"         #  ==> -1176
```

Comment: Or just print to a filehandle, like any sane.... wait-a-second, I was about to use sane and Perl in the same sentence.  What was I thinking?

Comment: Or just don't use implicit parentheses if you aren't sure how they'll be interpreted. Remember, folks, that shorthand is not mandatory.

Comment: It's not a list (as the void context warning indicates).

Comment: It is a list (as you can tell by the comma). The void context warning is about the useless `"\n"` in the 2nd element of the list.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to Perl's wacky parsing rules (oh Perl, you kook!), these statements:

```
print ((52-80)*42) , "\n";
print (52-80)*42 , "\n";
```

Are interpreted as if they were written:

```
(print ((52-80)*42)), "\n";
(print (52-80))*42, "\n";
```

This is why you end up seeing `-1176-28` on one line, and the expected blank line is missing. Perl sees `(print-expr), "\n";` and simply throws away the newline instead of printing it.

Comment: Any other choice would be just as wacky in other cases.  Unless your real complaint is that parentheses should always be required around all the arguments?