# Get keys of hash of hashes

Tags: perl

I'm trying to get the keys of hash of hashes and always have errors:

```
use strict;

my %oop_hash = ();
$oop_hash{'wfh'}{'ppb'} = "451103";
print (keys $oop_hash{'wfh'})."\n"; #1st try
print (keys %oop_hash{'wfh'})."\n"; #2nd try
```

How can I get the keys of hash of hashes?

Comment: add `use warnings` and you'll see what is wrong with it.

Comment: Your first version will work fine using Perl 5.14 and greater.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little tricky. The correct syntax is

```
keys %{$oop_hash{'wfh'}}
```

Also, as you've written it, your [print statement will not quite do what you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806368/). The `"\n"` will not get appended to the string because of the way Perl parses that line. You'll have to say one of:

```
print +(keys %{$oop_hash{'wfh'}}),"\n"; 
print ((keys %{$oop_hash{'wfh'}}),"\n");
```

Comment: I am confused, they both give me "1". I am using Perl v5.14.2.

Comment: Use comma operator, not concatenate (`.`) operator. The latter makes `keys` get evaluated in scalar context.

Answer (score 0):

here it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %oop_hash = ();
$oop_hash{'wfh'}{'ppb'} = "451103";
print join ", ", keys $oop_hash{'wfh'} , "\n"; # "ppb, "
```

Comment: and it is still "highly experimental"