# Why is there a + before the first left parenthesis following print in this Perl example?

Tags: perl

Recently I came across a statement like this

```
print +( map { $_ + 1 } @$_ ), "\n" for @$array; # <- AoA
```

I had not seen the `+` operator used with print like this before. Running the statement, it is not hard to infer what it is doing. But I am having trouble finding documentation on the `+` operator used this way.

```
my @tab = (
[1,2,3,4],
[qw(a b c d)],
);

my $test = "(", +( map { qq( >>$_<< ) } @$_ ), ")\n" for @tab;
print $test;
my @test = "(", +( map { qq( >>$_<< ) } @$_ ), ")\n" for @tab;
print @test;
my %test = "(", +( map { qq( >>$_<< ) } @$_ ), ")\n" for @tab;
print %test;
```

Above produces the warnings: `Useless use of a constant ()) in void context` for all three tests. `Use of uninitialized value` for the `scalar` test and `Odd number of elements in hash assignment` for both the `array` and `hash` tests, It would be nice to be able to store the statements output in a `scalar`. I know I can store an Identical string in a `scalar` using a for loop like below.

```
print "(", +( map { qq( >>$_<< ) } @$_ ), ")\n" for @tab;

my $out = '';
for (@tab) {
    $out .= "(" . ( join '', map { qq( >>$_<< ) } @$_ ) . ")\n";
}   
print $out;

# output ...
( >>1<<  >>2<<  >>3<<  >>4<< )
( >>a<<  >>b<<  >>c<<  >>d<< )
---
( >>1<<  >>2<<  >>3<<  >>4<< )
( >>a<<  >>b<<  >>c<<  >>d<< )
```

Why can't I store the statement in any variable or test its `type`. Id like in detail what is actually happening with the `print` builtin when using the `+` operator.

> **EDIT**: I belive my original post was kind of confusing, I did want to learn more about the `+` operator used with `print` but what I was really after is how to store each iteration of the shorthand `for` statement into a scalar string - I found a way after some testing ...

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @a = ([1,2,3],[qw/a b c/]);
my $one = '';
$one .= "(" . ( join '', map { " >>$_<< " } @$_ ) . ")\n" for @a;
print $one;

# output ...
( >>1<<  >>2<<  >>3<< )
( >>a<<  >>b<<  >>c<< )
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806368/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you've asked two questions here, so I'll answer both of them as well as I can...
Firstly, you're referring to the unary "+" operator, from [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Symbolic-Unary-Operators)

> Unary "+" has no effect whatsoever, even on strings. It is useful syntactically for separating a function name from a parenthesized expression that would otherwise be interpreted as the complete list of function arguments.

To expand on what exactly is going on in the print statement, I found the explanation on [perlmaven](http://perlmaven.com/the-magic-unary-plus) to be pretty good.

> The documentation explains that the + separates the print function from the parentheses ( and tells perl that these are not the parentheses wrapping the parameters of the print function.
>
> That might satisfy you, but if you are further intersted you can use the B::Deparse module to ask perl how does it understand this code-snippet:
>
> `print +(stat $filename)[7];`
>
> We save that content in the plus.pl file and run perl -MO=Deparse plus.pl. The result is:
>
> `print((stat $filename)[7]);`

Hope this is helpful!

**Edit**

Explaining in detail why you can't use the same command to print that sequence and assign it to a scalar is maybe outside of the scope of this question, but I'll attempt to briefly explain... with the note that if I'm wrong about something, I'd love a correction, I've come to understand how this works through writing code using this, not from reading the perl docs on its inner workings :)
With the print statement

`print "(", +( map { qq( >>$_<< ) } @$_ ), ")\n" for @tab;`

perl is interpreting it as

`(print "(", +( map { qq( >>$_<< ) } @$_ ), ")\n") for @tab;`

That is, it's grouping all of the stuff you want to print, and performing it for each element in @tab. However, with your scalar assignment

`my $test = "(", +( map { qq( >>$_<< ) } @$_ ), ")\n" for @tab;`

perl is performing the `for @tab` code on ")\n", thus your `Useless use of a constant ()) in void context` warning. To do what you want, you need to make it explicit *what* you want `for`'d

`my $test;
( $test .= "(" . join ('', ( map { qq( >>$_<< ) } @$_)) . ")\n") for @tab;
print $test;`

Should get you what you're looking for. Note the parenthesis around the entire assignment, and the omission of the unary "+" before the map, which is no longer necessary.

Comment: Thank you I know my post was confusing but the updated part of your answer was what I was looking for. I figured out how to do the same as what you have after some testing. ( I too learn by writing/running the code. docs are my last resort)

Comment: map alone returns a `list`, that is why join is need to return the results of `map` as a `scalar`. The `.` operator is needed to concat the other parts of the string into the scalar whereas the `,` operator would separate them into a `list` right?

Comment: Right. You're able to use `,` in your print because, from the [print perldoc] (http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html), print can accept a list of strings. :)

Answer (score 4):

[perldoc -f print](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#print):

> Be careful not to follow the
>               print keyword with a left parenthesis unless you want the
>               corresponding right parenthesis to terminate the arguments to the
>               print; put parentheses around all arguments (or interpose a "+",
>               but that doesn't look as good).

In this case, you do *not* want `map` to consume the `"\n"`, you must put parentheses around the `map { $_ + 1 } @$_`. But, the moment you do that you run into the situation described above unless you put a `+` before the left parenthesis so that `+(map { $_ + 1 } @$_)` becomes a single argument to print instead of `(map { $_ + 1 } @$_)` being interpreted as the complete argument list.

If you had

```
print ( map { $_ + 1 } @$_ ), "\n" for @$array;
```

the comma following the right parenthesis above would be interpreted as the comma operator. `print` would just print the numbers, and not the newline:

```
$ perl -we '$array=[[1,2,3]];print ( map { $_ + 1 } @$_ ), "\n" for @$array;'
print (...) interpreted as function at -e line 1.
Useless use of a constant ("\n") in void context at -e line 1.
234%
```

The `print` is evaluated. As a side effect, it prints the numbers. The return value of the `print` is discarded, and the value of the expression becomes `"\n"`. Since this value is not assigned to anything, you get the warning. Basically, the code ends up looking like:

```
"\n" for @$array;
```

except for the side effect of invoking `print`.

If you want to store the output of the loop in a variable, you can do:

```
my $string;
$string .= sprintf( "(%s)\n", join('', map {$_ + 1} @$_) ) for @tab;
```

Comment: okay great. one more question. is it possible to store the results of the single statement in a variable. Like `$scalar = "(", +( map { qq( >>$_<< ) } @$_ ), ")\n" for @tab;` So I can avoid building the `scalar` variable in a for loop as in my post.