# Perl string conversion

Tags: perl

Simple question about Perl 5.

As far as I understood in reading the first chapters of string conversion in perl, every string not containing numeric values used in a numeric operation gets automatically converted to the value of zero.

Just as testing I used the following print statements:

```
print 1 + ("barney " x 4);
print "\n";
print "barney " x 4 + 1;
print "\n";
print ("barney " x 4) + 1;
```

from this, I was expecting to receive as output always the number 1, as the string repetition operator has higher priority than the sum operator, but the output is the following:

```
1
1
barney barney barney barney
```

Why the last print statement doesn't print again 1, and Just prints "barney " four times? The last 1 also isn't printed at all

Comment: You have called `print` with the parameter `"barney " x 4` and added one to the result. `print("barney " x 4) + 1`

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806368/why-is-print-52-8042-different-than-print-4252-80-in-perl

Comment: Just to be sure : you are aware that `x` is the repetition operator whereas `*` is the multiplication?

Comment: Yes, awere of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always use strict and warnings; they point out your problem.

With respect to "every string not containing numeric values", that is vague but true.  If there is a number at the beginning of the string after leading whitespace is ignored, that will be the value.  So 0+"   123abc" is 123.

But "number" includes `/inf|nan/i`.  So 0+"nanotechnology" is NaN.

Another surprise is that the bitwise operators `~ & | ^` have a string mode; if neither operand is numeric or has been used in a numeric context, they will operate on the bits of the strings and return a string, instead of converting to numeric values.

And `++` also has a string mode: `++($x="abc")` is "abd".

Answer (score 4):

Turn on `warnings` to get more information:

```
print (...) interpreted as function at -e line 1.
Useless use of addition (+) in void context at -e line 1.
```

The last expression was interpreted as

```
(print ("barney " x 4)) + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have called `print` with the parameter `"barney " x 4` and added one to the result.

The parentheses in

```
print("barney " x 4) + 1
```

delimit the parameter list, just like most other languages