# Perl repeat string which has repeated substring

Tags: perl

I'm trying to print a string `fbeq00000000000000000000` using perl in the terminal.

To avoid typing so many zeros I'm using

```perl
 perl -e 'print "fbeq" . "0" x 20'
```

Now, I want to print `fbeq00000000000000000000` 20 times which I am trying to achieve with

```perl
 perl -e 'print "fbeq" . "0" x 20 x 20'
```

Which is giving me incorrect output : `fbeq0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

What I want is

`fbeq00000000000000000000fbeq00000000000000000000fbeq00000000000000000000fbeq00000000000000000000fbeq00000000000000000000 ....`

How do I achieve that?

Edit :
I have tried :
`perl -e 'print ("fbeq" . "0" x 20) x 20'` which gave incorrect results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use brackets:

```
perl -e 'print(("fbeq" . "0" x 20) x 20)'
```

Comment: Thanks! I did try brackets but incorrectly `perl -e 'print ("fbeq" . "0" x 20) x 20'
`

Comment: @skrrrt The issue with that other attempt is explained in [operators - Why is 'print (52-80)*42' different than 'print 42*(52-80)' in Perl? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806368/why-is-print-52-8042-different-than-print-4252-80-in-perl)

Comment: @skrrrt You don't really have to (the question is clear enough without), although if you do make sure that you include what's the behavior of that program too instead of just "it doesn't work".